# Layout перекрывает часть контента

Tags: android, android-layout

Проблема в следующем: Есть первый layout1 , поверх него, снизу layout2, при нажатии на кнопку меняю layout2.setVisibility(VISIBLE) тем самым проявляю layout2 только он прекрывает часть списка который в layout1 и элементы которые в самом низу попросту не видны и доступа к ним нету. Как сделать так чтобы layout1 сжимался при появлении layout2 или как впихнуть это дело в SnackBar?? Заранее благодарю

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.kombo.eplog.fragments.FragmentMusic">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeController"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/musiclist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDevider"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="13">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.6"
                android:background="?android:colorBackground">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/corners_background"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/note_48x48" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.85"
                android:background="?android:colorBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_name_of_composition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Любов і сон"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="21sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_name_of_artist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Авет Макарян"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.85">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/skip_prev"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_40dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.85">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/pl_pause"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_40dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2.85">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/skip_nxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_40dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код разметки.

Comment: Сделайте родителем layout NestedScrollView, поместите в него главный LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией, а затем уже в него вложите два ваших LinearLayout у первого высоту сделайте wrap_content и если при показе второго линера высота обоих будет выходить за пределы экрана то вы сможете прокручивать

Comment: Я попробывал и не получилось. Перрвый layout  полностью стянут к верху и отобтажется только полоска

Comment: Ну правильно, с вертикальной ориентацией так и будет, в первом линере у вас должны быть вью элементы и во втором, но второй вы будете программно делать видимым ведь

Comment: Может быть я немного тугой но я всеравно не понимаю как это сделать правильно

Comment: Перезалил разметку

Comment: Верхний будет пуст, потому что вью элементы которые в нем пустые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте 
1) менять прозрачность Alpha.
2) убирать layout remove
3) поместить в RelativeLayout, и  менять позицию

Comment: Проясните пожалуйста 2 и 3 пункт

Comment: **2)** Это с предка удалить елемент removeView(view), что бы не перекрывал, а потом добавить опять addView(view);, если нужно. **3)** это обернуть мешающий елемнт в RelativeLayout, и если он мешает выставлять setX(99999)

Comment: Спасибо большое)))